# Losing attributes from reference tags when publishing

Tags: html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, attributes, accordion

(This may be a WordPress issue. I've asked the question on their forum, too.)

Hello,

We want to include a collapsible accordion in our online documentation, built from Bootstrap components. We're using WordPress v4.2.4.

We are using the code below. On our web dev's machine, everything is fine.

On my machine, when I click **Publish/Update**, I lose the following attributes:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
```

How do I keep from losing these attributes? From our web dev:

> The data-* attributes are supposed to be supported, they're all valid and core HTML5.

Thanks!

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div id="heading1" class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Some title</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
<div id="heading2" class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Another title</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
<div id="heading3" class="panel-heading">
<h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Another title</a></h4>
</div>
<div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
<div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```